# Rails nested models failing validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing model spec tests using `rspec` for nested models 3 levels deep. Each `->` represents a `has_many` relationship.

`Users->Goals->Milestones`

Right now, my `spec/models/milestone_spec.rb` test is failing a `be_valid` check, and I'm a little stumped as to why this is happening.

```
Failures:

  1) Milestone 
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/milestone_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The spec itself:

```
describe Milestone do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:goal) { user.goals.build(content: "Loreum Ipsum", amount: "30", interval: 2) }
  before do
    @milestone = goal.milestones.build(amount: "20") 
  end

  subject { @milestone }

  it { should respond_to(:goal_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:amount) }
  # not sure why this isn't working
  it { should be_valid }
```

Could it be with how I'm creating the `@milestone`? I've tried `goal.milestones.new`, and that doesn't seem to make a difference. Below in the spec I have some tests for fields properly validating, and those run fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of trying to verify if it's valid, call `valid?` then check if the errors array is empty. That will give a more useful failure message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
it "should be valid" do
  @milestone.valid?
  puts @milestone.errors.full_messages
end
```

That will run the validations and print out the the validation errors for you so you can see what's going on.